# Linker Error when added custom h and m files iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

FlashHelper.m:

```
 #import "FlashHelper.h"

AVCaptureDevice* inputDevice;


@interface FlashHelper ()

@end

@implementation FlashHelper

-(id)init : (AVCaptureDevice*) device{
    self = [super init];
    inputDevice = device;
    return self;
}

-(void)turnOffFlash{
    [inputDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [inputDevice setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];//turn on flash and test
    [inputDevice unlockForConfiguration];
}

-(void)turnOnFlash{
    [inputDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [inputDevice setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];//turn on flash and test
    [inputDevice unlockForConfiguration];
}


@end
```

FlashHelper.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface FlashHelper : NSObject {

}
-(id)init : (AVCaptureDevice*) device;
-(void)turnOffFlash;
-(void)turnOnFlash;

@end
```

I wanted to add this as a helper class to my current iOS project. I keep getting the following error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEIQC.png)

I'm fairly new to Objective-C, Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Click on it, it should give you more information, and that's the one important. You can't declare `AVCaptureDevice* inputDevice;` like that "in the middle of nowhere". Change it with `@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice;` and put it between the `@interface FlashHelper ()` and `@end`. Then replace `inputDevice = device;` with `_inputDevice = device; that you should put in a `if (self)` test. Also, the `init:` method, would gain to be named like `-(id)initWithDevice:(AVCaptureDevice *)device`.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!